# How can I get the Selector dialog to include my prefabs

Tags: unity

When setting a variable for an object in Unity, for built-in types there is an option on the right-hand side to bring up a dialog that lists the possible values that can be chosen for that variable, for example when selecting a Sprite for a Sprite Renderer:

[image: Sprite Renderer]
[image: Select Sprite dialog]

Is it possible, and if so what do I need to do, to have that list populated with the prefabs within my project?

[image: Item Randomiser]
[image: Empty Item dialog]

In this example, there are a number of Item prefabs (both inside and outside the Resources folder if that makes a difference), however they do not appear in that dialog. Is there an attribute I am missing that needs to be specified on the Item class, or something else to enable this?

[image: Example Item prefab]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Item : MonoBehaviour, IIdentifiable, IFilterable
{
    [SerializeField]
    private int IdField;
    [SerializeField]
    private bool ActiveField;

    public int Id => IdField;
    public bool Active => ActiveField;
}


public class ItemRandomiser : MonoBehaviour, IWeightedObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    private List<string> NamesField;
    [SerializeField]
    private List<Item> ItemTemplatesField;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Item` is not an asset, it's a component. That dialog shows ASSETS of its type.

If you change `List<Item>` to `List<GameObject>`, you will see all the prefab assets in your project.

Or instead if you change `Item` from being a `MonoBehaviour` to being a `ScriptableObject`, then that dialog will show all the `Item` assets you created in your project.